# processing ! Sine wave

Tags: processing, trigonometry

I'm trying to display the x location when y has the highest value. In the if statement i tried to compare the y value with 120 but it seems it's never true so it doesn't display my x location using text function. I've also tried to round up the y value but still the result is not the one i wanted. Can anyone help me ?

Regards Antmar.

```java
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;

void setup() {
    background(150);
    size(800,200);
    smooth();
    line(0,100,width,100);
}

void draw() {

    //background(255);

    x += 0.5;


    y =map (sin(x/20),-1,1,80,120) ;


    noStroke();
    fill(#BBFFDD);
    ellipse(x, y , 1, 1);


    if ( y < 119 && y > 118.94) {

        textSize(10);
        text(x,x-10,y+20);
    } 
    println("x =",x,"|","y =",y);
}
```

Comment: This code prints out values at several X coordinates when I run it. What exactly did you expect this code to do? What exactly does this do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what your issue is. When I ran your code, it printed out your x-value at several places, but it was not doing this printing every time. To fix this, I first incremented x by `PI/4` instead of .5, to make it more likely to be close to 120. Then, I looked at the values of y, and the highest one was just a shade under 120. To print out the x-value at that point, I made the if-condition the following, as to only catch that one y-value. I also added another if-condition to get the value of x at the local maximums of this sin function:

```java
if ( y >= 100 + 19.999) {  
    textSize(10);
    text(x,x-10,y+20);
}else if(y <= 100 - 19.999){
    textSize(10);
    text(x,x+10,y-10);
}
```

Edit: After looking at the values of x and y, I found that incrementing x by `PI/4` leads to y having values of exactly 120 and 80 as minimums and maximums, so you can just check for those values instead, like so:

```java
if (y == 120) {
    textSize(10);
    text(x,x-10,y+20);
}else if(y == 80){
    textSize(10);
    text(x,x+10,y-10);
}
```

Comment: thanks !!!  it seems it does the trick! Do you have any specific reason for writing 100 + 19.999 ?  Sorry for the noob question but i do supose it's the same as 119.999 , no ?

Comment: Yeah, its the same. I just wanted to make it clear that the 19.999 difference was the same in both if-statements.